# Adjusting just the year of some data in R

Tags: r, date, formatting

I have a dataframe with 730 observations and one of the columns is a date column, all of the dates are supposed to be 2007 and I realise that a few seem to have been mistakenly entered as 2006. is there a way I can use R to select the 2005's and change them to 2008 without affecting the month and the day?

it is in date format in r and looks like this.

```
2005-05-21
```

Edit:

this is the output you asked for:

```
structure(c(13604, 13604, 13604, 13604, 13604, 13604, 13604, 
13604, 13604, 13604, 13604, 13604, 13604, 13604, 13604, 13604, 
13604, 13604, 13604, 13604, 13597, 13597, 13597, 13597, 13597, 
13597, 13597, 13597, 13597, 13597, 13598, 13598, 13598, 13598, 
13598, 13598, 13598, 13598, 13598, 13598, 13607, 13607, 13607, 
13607, 13607, 13607, 13607, 13607, 13607, 13607, 13607, 13607, 
13607, 13607, 13607, 13607, 13607, 13607, 13607, 13607, 13607, 
13607, 13607, 13607, 13607, 13607, 13607, 13607, 13607, 13607, 
13607, 13607, 13607, 13607, 13607, 13607, 13607, 13607, 13607, 
13607, 13608, 13608, 13608, 13608, 13608, 13608, 13608, 13608, 
13608, 13608, 13608, 13608, 13608, 13608, 13608, 13608, 13608, 
13608, 13608, 13608, 13598, 13598, 13598, 13598, 13598, 13598, 
13598, 13598, 13598, 13598, 13598, 13598, 13598, 13598, 13598, 
13598, 13598, 13598, 13598, 13598, 13597, 13597, 13597, 13597, 
13597, 13597, 13597, 13597, 13597, 13597, 13597, 13597, 13597, 
13597, 13597, 13597, 13597, 13597, 13597, 13597, 13605, 13605, 
13605, 13605, 13605, 13605, 13605, 13605, 13605, 13605, 13605, 
13605, 13605, 13605, 13605, 13605, 13605, 13605, 13605, 13605, 
13608, 13608, 13608, 13608, 13608, 13608, 13608, 13608, 13608, 
13608, 13608, 13608, 13608, 13608, 13608, 13608, 13608, 13608, 
13608, 13608, 13244, 13244, 13244, 13244, 13244, 13244, 13244, 
13244, 13244, 13244, 13244, 13244, 13244, 13244, 13244, 13244, 
13244, 13244, 13244, 13244, 13600, 13600, 13600, 13600, 13600, 
13600, 13600, 13600, 13600, 13600, 13600, 13600, 13600, 13600, 
13600, 13600, 13600, 13600, 13600, 13600, 13613, 13613, 13613, 
13613, 13613, 13613, 13613, 13613, 13613, 13613, 13613, 13613, 
13613, 13613, 13613, 13613, 13613, 13613, 13613, 13613, 13613, 
13610, 13610, 13610, 13610, 13610, 13610, 13610, 13610, 13610, 
13610, 13610, 13610, 13610, 13610, 13610, 13610, 13610, 13610, 
13610, 13610, 13610, 13616, 13616, 13616, 13616, 13616, 13616, 
13616, 13616, 13616, 13616, 13616, 13616, 13616, 13616, 13616, 
13616, 13616, 13616, 13616, 13616, 13616, 13616, 13616, 13616, 
13616, 13616, 13616, 13616, 13616, 13616, 13616, 13616, 13616, 
13616, 13616, 13616, 13616, 13616, 13616, 13616, 13618, 13618, 
13618, 13618, 13618, 13618, 13618, 13618, 13618, 13618, 13618, 
13618, 13618, 13618, 13618, 13618, 13618, 13618, 13618, 13618, 
13621, 13621, 13621, 13621, 13621, 13621, 13621, 13621, 13621, 
13621, 13621, 13621, 13621, 13621, 13621, 13621, 13621, 13621, 
13621, 13621, 13622, 13622, 13622, 13622, 13622, 13622, 13622, 
13622, 13622, 13622, 13622, 13622, 13622, 13622, 13622, 13622, 
13622, 13622, 13622, 13622, 13620, 13620, 13620, 13620, 13620, 
13620, 13620, 13620, 13620, 13620, 13620, 13620, 13620, 13620, 
13620, 13620, 13620, 13620, 13620, 13620, 13622, 13622, 13622, 
13622, 13622, 13622, 13622, 13622, 13622, 13622, 13622, 13622, 
13622, 13622, 13622, 13622, 13622, 13622, 13622, 13622, 13622, 
13622, 13622, 13623, 13623, 13623, 13623, 13623, 13623, 13623, 
13623, 13623, 13623, 13623, 13623, 13623, 13623, 13623, 13623, 
13623, 13623, 13623, 13623, 13623, 14080, 14080, 14080, 14080, 
14080, 14080, 14080, 14080, 14080, 14080, 14080, 14080, 14080, 
14080, 14080, 14080, 14080, 14080, 14080, 14080, 14080, 14081, 
14082, 14083, 14084, 14085, 14086, 14087, 14088, 14089, 14090, 
14091, 14092, 14093, 14094, 14095, 14096, 14097, 14098, 14099, 
14100, 14101, 14102, 14103), class = "Date")sked for
```

Comment: Please post the output of `dput(yourdataframe$datecolumn)` so we can exactly understand the class, format etc of the column

Comment: e.g. if your column is of type character, maybe you can simply do this: `yourDF$dateCol <- gsub('2005','2008',yourDF$dateCol)`

Comment: OP said "it is in date format"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep it as a date format you can do the following with lubridate

```
library(lubridate)

year(yourDF$date)[year(yourDF$date)==2005] <- 2008
```

Here's an example....

```
df <- data.frame(date =Sys.Date() - 1:4, Col2 = 1:4)

df
        date Col2
1 2016-04-20    1
2 2016-04-19    2
3 2016-04-18    3
4 2016-04-17    4

# In my example i'll change the year from 2016 to 2008

year(df$date)[year(df$date)==2016] <- 2008

df
        date Col2
1 2008-04-20    1
2 2008-04-19    2
3 2008-04-18    3
4 2008-04-17    4
```

Comment: Well it worked for me.  Just make sure you install and load the lubridate package.

Comment: `> df
        date
1 2005-01-01
2 2005-01-01
3 2008-01-01
4 2008-01-01
> library(lubridate)
> year(df$date)[year(df$date)==2005] = 2008
Error in checkSlotAssignment(object, name, value) : 
  assignment of an object of class “logical” is not valid for slot ‘.Data’ in an object of class “Period”; is(value, "numeric") is not TRUE
In addition: Warning message:
In Ops.factor(per@.Data, num) : ‘+’ not meaningful for factors`

Comment: I edited my answer to include a short example to show it it works.

Comment: Interesting. It does work for your case(two columns data frame) and it's not working for my case(single column data frame).

Comment: That's an easier way to change ALL of the years to 2008, but the OP mentioned that they mistakenly wrote 2005 instead of 2008 so this code would change ONLY the 2005 entries.

Answer (score 1):

assuming your date is

```
x <- as.Date('2005/01/01')
```

you can try

```
d <- as.POSIXlt(x)
d$year <- d$year+3
result <- as.Date(d)
```

result should be:
[1] "2008-01-01"

Comment: ?! my example shows how to convert one date, what do you mean?

Comment: I meant that if the OP used your method, it would add 3 to every year which would only be desirable if all the years were 2005.

Comment: `d$year[d$year==105] <- 108` should do it if you need a selection

Answer (score 0):

if you are reading the dates as character, 
you can simply use a regular expression.

The idea is the following:

```
gsub("^2005", "2008","2005-05-21")

#output
[1] "2008-05-21"
```

NB: "^2005": if the string starts with "2005"

Let's assume an extract from your data:

```
data <- structure(c(13604, 13604, 13604, 13604, 13604, 13604, 13604), class = "Date")

#check
data
[1] "2007-04-01" "2007-04-01" "2007-04-01" "2007-04-01" "2007-04-01" "2007-04-01" "2007-04-01"

#substitution, with class conversion
data2 <- as.Date(gsub("^2007", "2008", data))

#output
data2

[1] "2008-04-01" "2008-04-01" "2008-04-01" "2008-04-01" "2008-04-01" "2008-04-01" "2008-04-01"

#check
class(data2)
[1] "Date"
```